# compile problem for xcode 3.2

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

Hey I have problem compiling code in xcode 3.2
I have a code where it's using iOS 4's API, "MFMessageComposeViewController"
It would compile fine with 4.0 under xcode, but when when i try to compile with 3.2 I get error because of "MFMessageComposeViewController".
It seems that xcode can't find keyword for MFMessageComposeViewController.
In order to be able to compile for 4.0 and 3.2 and still use MFMessageComposeViewController, what should i do?
thank you!

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't determine whether the version numbers you are referring to are to do with the iPhone OS version of the Xcode version.

The documentation for [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) shows that it is only available in iOS 4.0 and later, so you can't use it at all in earlier versions of iPhone OS.

If you are having trouble with Xcode version 4, you cannot ask for help here because it is under a non-disclosure agreement, as far as I am aware. If you are using Xcode 3.2 to compile for source code targeting iOS 4.0, ensure that your project settings are correct and are set to use the iOS 4.0 SDK.

Comment: i have solve the problem.
just set base sdk to 4.0 and iOS deployment target to 3.0 and set framework of MessageUI.framework to "weak" link and it will work!